# WPF. Shortcut in mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a button.
I want her to react to the shift + mouse click using mvvm

i try to do this:

XAML:

```
<Button>
  <Button.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding AAA}" Gesture="Shift+LeftClick" />
  </Button.InputBindings>
</Button>
```

c#:

```
private RelayCommand _aaa;

        public RelayCommand AAA
        {
            get
            {
                return _aaa ??(_aaa =new RelayCommand(ExecuteAAA, CanExecuteAAA));
            }
        }

        private void ExecuteAAA()
        {    
            MessageBox.Show("111");
        }

       private bool CanExecuteAAA()
        {
            return true;
        }
```

But it dont work.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code as far as I can tell. The gesture definition is correct and works if the binding is correct. Have you checked the output window for binding errors?

Comment: i have checked the output window for binding errors. It is ok

Comment: Does this work for normal click? <Button Command="{Binding AAA}" />

Answer (score 0):

it work!

XAML:

```
<Button Command="{Binding AAA}" />
```

c#:

```
private RelayCommand _aaa;

        public RelayCommand AAA
        {
            get
            {
                return _aaa ??(_aaa =new RelayCommand(ExecuteAAA, CanExecuteAAA));
            }
        }

        private void ExecuteAAA()
        {    
          if (System.Windows.Forms.Control.ModifierKeys == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift)
          {
             MessageBox.Show("111");
          }
        }

       private bool CanExecuteAAA()
        {
            return true;
        }
```